# Is there a limit of emails/pictures per Gravatar account?

Tags: cdn, image-hosting

I'm building a site to connect patients to doctors. Each doctor will have a profile picture. I'm quite happy to manually maintain the profile pictures as there won't be that many doctors nor will they have a need to change their picture very often, if at all.

I thought of using Gravatar to host all these profile pictures. The idea is to create a single Gravatar account then keep adding email addresses to it in the form firstname.lastname@mysite.com and associating each one with a new image.

Does anyone know, however, if I will run into any per-account limit? If so, it wouldn't be feasible because I would end up with a bunch of Gravatar accounts instead of just the one.

Comment: Last time I had to manage a large amount of profile photos, I made a MySQL database and stored them in Base64 as a string in the database with their account details. It would be no big deal to change the photos either, just update the field with the new encoded image. (Shrink them and resize first).

Answer (score -1):

There are plenty of php libraries for editing images and keeping them scaled to any square size. You're better off using a custom application to let users upload rather than using gravatars API.

Though you may consider integrating with Facebooks API and once users authorize you can download their facebook photo and be clear it is only for their photo the authentication.

Comment: I'd -1 this if I had sufficient rep. Please limit alternatives to comments. I am not using PHP. And for various reasons that are outside the scope of this question, I am not associating doctors with facebook profiles and/or pages.